# How to stop observers in Observable.merge?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5, rxjs6

I have a method that creates timer:

```
 create(options: any) {
    return timer(0, 1000).pipe(
      map(() => {
        return options;
      }),
      takeWhile(() => new Date() < options.finishDate)
    );
  }
```

Then this timer I add to array `this.timers` of Observables:

```
this.timers.push(this.create({finishDate: new Date()}))
```

When I merge observers:

```
this.mergeObserver = Observable.merge(this.timers).subscribe(x => {
   console.log(x);
});
```

I see that `console.log(x);` continues work despite timer was finished.

Why? And how to stop all timers in array?

I can unsubscribe  here:

```
 Observable.merge(this.timers).subscribe(x => {
   x.unsubscribe();
});
```

But it does not stop `Observable.merge`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.mergeObserver = Observable.merge(this.timers).subscribe(x => {
   console.log(x);
});
```

In this case mergeObserver is not an observable but a subscription. The subscribe method returns a subscription. So renaming this to mergeSubscription and calling unsubscribe on this object is how to unsubscribe.

If you want a reference to the observable you need to subscribe after you have taken a reference.

```
this.mergeObserver = Observable.merge(this.timers);

this.mergeSubscription = this.mergeObserver.subscribe(x => {
   console.log(x);
});
```

and then you unsubscribe with the mergeSubscription object.

```
Observable.merge(this.timers).subscribe(x => {
   x.unsubscribe();
});
```

Here you cannot call unsubscribe on x as x is the value that comes out of the merged timers. When one of the timers emits then the merge will emit that value as well, it is just a number and does not have an unsubscribe method.

Comment: Could you tell me, where I should run `Observable.merge(this.timers);` when I add a new element to array `this.timers`?

Comment: And how to stop specific timer in array, when I delete element from array?

Comment: Merge is not dynamic like that, Observable.merge(this.timers) creates a new observable and if you want to add a new observable or remove an existing one to the merged observable you cannot do that dynamically. You would need to manage an array of subscriptions that pass the value to a subject and handle the adding and removing yourself. I don't know of an operator that will manage it for you.